# Datatables not showing the button for detail

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I trying to use datatables on my web, but after i add every thing on my web, it does not show the thing like the template i saw.
This is the template
[image]
And this is the thing i got
[image]

i mean i can not see the plus button so that i can not see the detail of the product.
This button just show when i make browser become smaller like this, but i need that even when the browser is large like in the template
[image]

Do you have any idea, please help?
This is the template that i follow:
https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/display-types/foundation-modal.html
This is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#example').DataTable( {
    responsive: {
        details: {
            display: $.fn.dataTable.Responsive.display.modal( {
                header: function ( row ) {
                    var data = row.data();
                    return 'Details for '+data[0]+' '+data[1];
                }
            } ),
            renderer: function ( api, rowIdx, columns ) {
                var data = $.map( columns, function ( col, i ) {
                    return '<tr>'+
                            '<td>'+col.title+':'+'</td> '+
                            '<td>'+col.data+'</td>'+
                        '</tr>';
                } ).join('');

                return $('<table width="100%"/>').append( data );
            }
        }
    }
} );
```

} );

Comment: You have to show your code

Comment: i did add my script, can you help me?

Comment: Do you include all css files as in the example ?

Comment: yep i include all css and jquery file in the example

Answer (score 8):

**For anyone still finding this in 2018**

I found out the issue with my 'plus' buttons not appearing ( when in a responsive, mobile view ) was because they are appended to the 'first child' of the row, so if a row other than the first is given responsive priority over that row then the button disappears along with it.

Comment: have you found solution ?

Comment: yes, this was a while ago but if I remember correctly it has to do with the responsive priority option you give to each column. The problem occurs when the buttons have a lower priority so they disappear as the screen size reduces

Comment: I haven't included the right css file, it was so silly of me, anyways thanks

Comment: For me, it turned out to be the wrong version of datatables responsive js via cdn.

Answer (score 2):

the best answer is use "responsivePriority", by default all priority is 10,000 if you want change it set by yourself, for example:

```
sortable: false,
data: "Id",
className: 'details-control',
responsivePriority: 1
```

Comment: This is correct answer and proper usage of API functionality. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Anyone looking for Bootstrap(I am using ver 5.0 alpha1) backed responsive datatables, here is what I did and it "just" works:

```
<link rel="stylesheet"
    th:href="@{/css/bootstrap.css}" />
<link rel="stylesheet"
    th:href="@{/webjars/datatables/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css}" />
<link rel="stylesheet"
    th:href="@{/webjars/datatables-responsive/2.2.3/css/responsive.bootstrap4.min.css}" />


<your> html code here </your>


<div th:fragment="import_scripts">
<script type="text/javascript"
        th:src="@{/webjars/jquery/jquery.min.js}"></script>
<script th:src="@{/webjars/datatables/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js}"></script>
<script th:src="@{/webjars/popper.js/umd/popper.min.js}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
        th:src="@{/js/bootstrap.js}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
        th:src="@{/webjars/datatables/1.10.20/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js}"></script>
<script th:src="@{/webjars/datatables-responsive/2.2.3/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js}"></script>
<script th:src="@{/webjars/datatables-responsive/2.2.3/js/responsive.bootstrap4.min.js}"></script>
```

You can change the path to your own css/js files, but the **important part** here **is the sequence of these files**. Make sure you have properly placed the CSSs and JSs in the above mentioned sequence.

Here is the final outcome:

[image]

> Also, sometimes its the version numbers too for the CSS/JS libs
> can make a difference.

I am using these : JQuery 3.5.1, PopperJS 1.16.0, Datatable 1.10.20

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the reason not about "javascript".You can check your html or css ,through the comparison of your two images,your frame structrue should have some problems;when the browser window is larger,you can f12 to see those code is exists:

```
table.dataTable.dtr-inline.collapsed>tbody>tr>th:first-child:before {
  top: 8px;
  left: 4px;
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 16px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px #444;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
  text-indent: 4px;
  line-height: 16px;
  content: '+';
  background-color: #008CBA;
```

}

beacause the code determines the existence of this button.Hope it can help you!
LIKE this:
[image]

Comment: you mean that, i have to put my code in a div and make the size for that div by css right?

Comment: No,beacause you use datatable,these css contain your introduction.eg:"https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.0.0/css/responsive.foundation.min.css",you just need to "f12" to check these elements is exist.

Comment: it is not exist on my code, or maybe i just link the css to an online page

Comment: through it,you can find the reason about your problem;

Comment: ye,it did't not exist your code ,so of course,the button don't show .Know reason ,you can resolve it :));

Answer (score 0):

I also hidden the control icon, so I solved the problem was to add the property:

```
 type: 'column'
```

Based on the example in the question, it would look like this:

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
    responsive: {
        details: {
            type:'column',
            display: $.fn.dataTable.Responsive.display.modal( {
                header: function ( row ) {
                    var data = row.data();
                    return 'Details for '+data[0]+' '+data[1];
                }
            } ),
            renderer: function ( api, rowIdx, columns ) {
                var data = $.map( columns, function ( col, i ) {
                    return '<tr>'+
                            '<td>'+col.title+':'+'</td> '+
                            '<td>'+col.data+'</td>'+
                        '</tr>';
                } ).join('');

                return $('<table width="100%"/>').append( data );
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If You want to show **search boxes in Header** The Just Write **CSS** LIke Below...
**In Datatable...**

```
tfoot {display: table-header-group;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your css

```
table.dataTable.dtr-inline.collapsed>tbody>tr>td.dtr-control, table.dataTable.dtr-inline.collapsed>tbody>tr>th.dtr-control {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
table.dataTable.dtr-inline.collapsed>tbody>tr.parent>td.dtr-control:before, table.dataTable.dtr-inline.collapsed>tbody>tr.parent>th.dtr-control:before {
    content: "-";
    background-color: #d33333;
}
table.dataTable.dtr-inline.collapsed>tbody>tr>td.dtr-control:before, table.dataTable.dtr-inline.collapsed>tbody>tr>th.dtr-control:before {
    top: 33%;
    left: 5px;
    height: 1em;
    width: 1em;
    margin-top: -5px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    border: .15em solid white;
    border-radius: 1em;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0.2em #444;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    text-align: center;
    text-indent: 0 !important;
    font-family: "Courier New",Courier,monospace;
    line-height: 1em;
    content: "+";
    background-color: #31b131;
}
```

add this in you JS

targets": [0]-index for which column it want to show

view_tbl = $('#tbl').DataTable({
"ajax": {
"url": url,
"type": "POST",
data: {
action: load_action
}
},
"responsive": true,
"columnDefs": [
**{className: "dtr-control", "targets": [0]},**

Answer (score 0):

I was using this with node and didn't have the css imported.
I added this to my `app.scss` and voilá!

```
@import "~datatables.net-responsive-bs4/css/responsive.bootstrap4.min.css";
```